# Meta-site bug - reputation does not change unless you act as if you're about to ask a question

Tags: bug

I found that when my reputation increases on main site, it will not show any difference on the meta site until i go to ask a question. Is this a bug or a deliberate measure implemented, if the latter, why? 
(I don't have to actually ask a question just visit the page where i'd type to create a question)

Comment: Most probably cacheing. I think you should ask this or search for it first on meta.stackexchange.com since this is not related to this website only.... most probably.

Comment: Alright @Marius thank you, noted, I'll do this tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, Answer can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96606/my-meta-rep-on-photo-se-differs-from-my-main-rep). As meta user kiamlaluno says:

The reputation on meta sites is not updated instantly (except for this site, Meta Stack Exchange, which is not a typical per-site meta), after you get more reputation in the main site, but it is updated once per hour, according to the [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (**synchronized hourly**), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.